# Building android source code and making changes

Tags: android, android-source

I have downloaded the android source code and built it. I am making changes to a couple of files and then run `mmm /folder`. After that do I need to run make again or will it be automatically reflected to my system.img?

Comment: Is this question really any sillier than the 100th "OnClickHandler doesn't work because I'm getting and NPE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly do not understand why people are voting this down, without comment.

`mmm` rebuilds the entire image.  You do not need to run make, after you run it.